# Out of memory when cropping a bitmap with .Clone()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to automatically generate a thumbnail from an image uploaded by a user but I keep getting the exception "Out of memory".
From what I understand the out of memory exception is thrown when you specify a starting position or a width/height that's outside of the image but even if I do this

```
var rct = new Rectangle(5, 5, 10, 10);
var whatever = bitmap.Clone(rct, bitmap.PixelFormat);
```

on an image that is 800x900 pixels I still get the "Out of memory" exception, I can't figure out what's wrong with it and I can't really get any good answers from other threads since everything regarding the OOM exception is just the mistake of going outside the image boundaries. 
Does anyone have an explanation or solution to this?

EDIT: A bit more context

The loop for the images.

```
foreach (var blob in fileInfoList)
{
    var blockBlobName = CheckExistence(BaseBlobUrl, blob.FileName, blob.FileNameWithoutExtension);

    var image = new Image()
    {
        BlobUrl = Path.Combine(BaseBlobUrl, blockBlobName),
        FullName = blob.FileName,
        FileName = blob.FileNameWithoutExtension,
        BlockBlobName = blockBlobName,
        OwningOrganizationId = CurrentUser.UserOrganization.OrganizationId,
        ThumbnailUrl = CreateThumbnail(blob.File, blockBlobName),
        Name = "Whatever"
    };

    blobList.Add(image);

    RepositoryFactory.AzureStorageRepository.SaveImage(blob.File, blockBlobName, blob.ContentType, CurrentUser.UserOrganization.Organization.Id);
}
```

The method that is being called by each image in the list to generate the thumbnail.

```
public string CreateThumbnail(byte[] b, string parentImageName)
    {
        Bitmap bmp;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(b))
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
        }

        Bitmap thumbnail = bmp;

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(5, 5, 10, 10);

        if (bmp.Width > bmp.Height)
            thumbnail = bmp.Clone(rect, bmp.PixelFormat);
        else if (bmp.Height > bmp.Width)
            thumbnail = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle((bmp.Height/2) - (bmp.Width/2), 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Width), bmp.PixelFormat);

        byte[] bmpArray = new byte[0];

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            finalCrop.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            ms.Close();

            bmpArray = ms.ToArray();
        }

        var name = "Thumbnail_" + parentImageName;

        RepositoryFactory.AzureStorageRepository.SaveThumbnail(bmpArray, name, "jpg/image", CurrentUser.UserOrganization.Organization.Id);

        return BaseBlobUrl + "thumbnails/" + name;


    }
```

Comment: You do this in a loop, don't you?

Comment: The method for generating the thumbnails is called from within a loop since a user can upload several images at the same time.

Comment: OOM can also confusingly be raised when the input file is not in a supported format.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of your code then, including the loop context

Comment: I added a bit more context in my OP.

Comment: Note that you're never `Dispose`ing the image/bitmap; that's a very bad idea, since there's plenty of native resources associated with the object, some of which are quite limited (e.g. the GDI+ handles). GDI+ isn't really designed to be used on a server anyway, so be careful. Does the problem happen with all images you've tried? I can't reproduce the issue you're seeing, Note that OOM from GDI+ can mean many different errors, not just OOM or bounds errors. Where exactly are you getting the exception?

Comment: You don't seem to be disposing of the bitmaps you create anywhere. Unless you are returning the bitmap to something, you should add a `using` block for your bitmaps.

Comment: Okay I will add a using block for the bitmaps.

Comment: I have tried on four different images (two .jpgs, one .png and one .gif) and they all throw an exception at the same line. 
It's on the "thumbnail = bmp.Clone(rect, bmp.PixelFormat)" each time.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you're getting here is that Bitmaps need to be disposed. If one gets garbage collected without releasing its underlying unmanaged content (i.e. being disposed), then that memory can not be recovered...

Also note that you will need to dispose both bitmaps. Best thing to do is wrap them in a using, something like this:

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(b))
        {
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms))
            using (Bitmap thumbnail = bmp)
            {

                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(5, 5, 10, 10);

                if (bmp.Width > bmp.Height)
                    thumbnail = bmp.Clone(rect, bmp.PixelFormat);
                else if (bmp.Height > bmp.Width)
                    thumbnail = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle((bmp.Height / 2) - (bmp.Width / 2), 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Width), bmp.PixelFormat);

                byte[] bmpArray = new byte[0];

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    finalCrop.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    ms.Close();

                    bmpArray = ms.ToArray();
                }

                var name = "Thumbnail_" + parentImageName;

                RepositoryFactory.AzureStorageRepository.SaveThumbnail(bmpArray, name, "jpg/image", CurrentUser.UserOrganization.Organization.Id);

                return BaseBlobUrl + "thumbnails/" + name;
            }
        }
```

It is worth noting that `using` will call `Dispose()` on it's target, even if an exception is thrown (thus having the same `finally` type functionality as @Scott Chamberlain answer

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I found an answer to my problem by disposing the Bitmaps.
After this bit of code

```
Bitmap thumbnail = bmp;
```

I added

```
bmp.Dispose();
```

And during debugging I noticed that none of the properties from bmp were left in the Bitmap called thumbnail so I changed it into the following

```
Bitmap thumbnail = new Bitmap(bmp);
```

Thank you all for telling me to dispose the Bitmaps!

Comment: I would either use `using` blocks or put the `bmp.Dispose()` in a try/finally block. Also, you put that dispose in the wrong spot, it needs to go after the two `thumbnail = bmp.Clone` lines. Lastlly you never dispose of `thumbnail`.

Comment: I have posted an answer showing the correct way to do it. Your current way has some major bugs in it that you will not see right away but may make your program crash randomly after running for several hours.

Comment: Yes I will be using >using blocks instead for all the Bitmaps in the method. The >bmp Bitmap is no longer necessary for the >Clone lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct way to properly dispose of your objects.

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
Bitmap thumbnail = null;

try
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(b))
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
    }

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(5, 5, 10, 10);

    if (bmp.Width > bmp.Height)
        thumbnail = bmp.Clone(rect, bmp.PixelFormat);
    else if (bmp.Height > bmp.Width)
        thumbnail = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle((bmp.Height/2) - (bmp.Width/2), 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Width), bmp.PixelFormat);
    else
        thumbnail = bmp;



    byte[] bmpArray = new byte[0];

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        finalCrop.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        ms.Close();

        bmpArray = ms.ToArray();
    }

    var name = "Thumbnail_" + parentImageName;

    RepositoryFactory.AzureStorageRepository.SaveThumbnail(bmpArray, name, "jpg/image", CurrentUser.UserOrganization.Organization.Id);

    return BaseBlobUrl + "thumbnails/" + name;
}
finally
{
    if(bmp != null)
        bmp.Dispose();

    if(thumbnail != null)
        thumbnail.Dispose(); //If bmp and thumbnail are the same object this is still safe to do.
}
```

Use a try/finally block to ensure that even in the event of a error your objects get disposed. Doing the extra `Bitmap thumbnail = new Bitmap(bmp);` in your answer just makes a extra bitmap you are forgetting to dispose.

Answer (score 1):

I received this Exception when the **Rectangle** used to crop the image was partly **outside the bounds** of the image.